# What cluster is the pyspark shell connected to?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Beginner question, just started learning about Spark today.

The tutorial first guides me to run `pyspark`, eg.

`./spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark`

This spins up a shell, and *magically* gives me a `sc` and `spark` instance. I can use them to load local files and do simple operations.

`sc` is `<SparkContext master=local[*] appName=PySparkShell>`

My question is: What Spark cluster is this shell connected to?

My understanding is that a spark cluster must be ran first, then we can connect to it with a client, and python (via pyspark) is one of the languages for a client.

My goal is to find out what cluster this shell is connected to, so I can configure the cluster to be able to load files from S3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to say given the information you've provided.

- If `spark.master` is set in `spark-defaults.conf` it is the value.
- Otherwise it uses `local[*]`

When in doubt check Spark UI or `spark.sparkContext.master` / `sc.master`.

Comment: The master is set to local[*], what does that mean? Where is the cluster running? Who ran the cluster? Is the cluster running as a service? (sorry for the many questions, I'm pretty confused)

Answer (score 0):

You have set the master as local which means everything will run on local machine.

So in case you want to run on cluster you will have to set up the cluster accordingly and use master as yarn-cluster.

Also, if you can try master as yarn-client which means the cluster and your interactive shell or execution is happening on same node.

By default interactive shell runs on local or yarn-client mode. To check the cluster details you can look for spark configuration files. You can try using  `setMaster("yarn-cluster")`

I am not sure if that will work in interactive mode. You can also try one more option while entering into interactive shell

```
pyspark --master yarn-cluster
```

These two options, I am suggesting, I am not sure if they will work with interactive shell. I will update you by testing it.